# Как заставить TypeScript корректно проверять выражения?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Простой пример:

```
const isString = (any: any): boolean => (typeof any === 'string')

function something(foo: string | number): string {
  const value = isString(foo) ? foo : Number.prototype.toFixed.call(foo)
  // ... какие-то действия
  return value
}
```

После первой строки, внутри функции, тут же светятся ошибки. TypeScript не способен корректно обработать строку с кастомной `isString(foo)`- константа `value`, видится ему как `string | number`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если же явно использовать `typeof` и написать так ...

```
function something(foo: string | number): string {
  const value = typeof foo === 'string' ? foo : Number.prototype.toFixed.call(foo)
  return value
}
```

... то `const value: string` и ошибок, соответственно, нет.

Принудительная установка типа...

```
/** @type {string} */
const value = ...
```

...также не помогает.

Не могу найти настройки [конфига](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig), где подобное поведение возможно исправить.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates

```
const isString = (x: any): x is string => typeof x === 'string'
```

Comment: А ссылка на документацию? Как я понимаю после `is` можно любой тип прописать?

Comment: @AlexanderLonberg, добавил.

Comment: Работает даже с JS `@returns {any is string}` и это замечательно.